# CSS property, height, not dynamically changing to account for text height

Tags: javascript, html, css

[Here's the code on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n75bv3qj/7/).

Here's the script.

```
function toggle(divId, tog) {
  var div = document.getElementById(divId);
  div.classList.toggle(tog);
}

function toggleSize(divId, tog, textId) {
  var div = document.getElementById(divId);
  div.classList.toggle(tog);
  div.getElementsByClass(tog)[0].style.height = window.getComputedStyle(textId).getPropertyValue('height');
}
```

What I tried doing is get the height value of the contained text, and assign that to the outer div.
But, the height is not updating.

Another way to word it is that I want the height to adjust to the overflowed content.

Any ideas?

Comment: can you tell what actually you are trying to do?

Comment: Do you want to consider of using Jquery?

Comment: In the code on JSFiddle, when you click the second button, the height of the box doesn't change to the text height. EDIT: And when you change the size of the window, the box doesn't change with the text height.

Comment: However, when using a simple "display: none" to "display: block" does what I want to achieve. I just want to add a lil' transition.

Comment: Another way to word it is that I want the height to adjust to the overflowed content.

Comment: use window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById(textId)).height

Comment: Height automatically adjusts, and has since HTML was invented more than two decades ago. But you can't transition on height. You have to transition on `max-height`. You should almost never need to use `getComputedStyle`. If you want to get an elements height (but why?), then use `getClientBoundingRect`. if you want more help as to why your elements are not self-adjusting, provide more HTML and/or CSS in the question.